# Searching for multiple solutions with NDpend

Tags: ndepend

Is there a way with NDepend to have it search for sln files to load?  I need to look at metrics across a large codebase that has hundreds of sln files in it.  I want to create some summary info, like total lines of code.  In the interface I can browse to sln files but that will take me a long long time.

The perfect solution would be to just select a top directory and then have it recurse looking for the sln files automatically...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by writing a program based on NDepend.API. See the [getting started with NDepend.API page](http://www.ndepend.com/api/webframe.html?NDepend.API_gettingstarted.html).

Basically your program will recursively search for all *.sln files under the top directory.

For each solution file it'll call [GetAssembliesFromVisualStudioSolutionOrProject()](http://www.ndepend.com/api/webframe.html?NDepend.API~NDepend.DotNet.VisualStudio.IVisualStudioManager~GetAssembliesFromVisualStudioSolutionOrProject.html).

Once you gathered all assemblies file paths from all .sln files, you aggregate them in a newly created NDepend project.

The getting started page shows how to create such project and eventually run a first analysis if you have a build machine license (else the analysis will be ran from VisualNDepend.exe).